# "Myfanpage on facebook" how to add this "on facebook" line?

Tags: facebook

I added likebox to my site, I want to look it like http://society6.com/ (at the bottom of the page). My likebox only displays the name of my fanpage. How to add this "on facebook" part?  Also, my fan page is something facebook.com/pages/myfanpagename/32323523433 How to edit my fan page name to facebook.com/myfanpage Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin settings [plugin settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), deselect "Show header" check box. I wanted to send an attachment but I'm a new user and it's not allowed. Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: changing name is allowed after you have 25 fans, When you do get them, go to: https://www.facebook.com/username/ choose your page from the dropdown menu and choose the name. If available you can set the new name for it. No spaces allowed. They explain there very well.

Answer (score 0):

> cool! Thanks! And what about url?

if u have more then 25 fans (or some more ) then you can create  your own facebook fanpage username .. facebook.com/`fanpage_user_username`

[check](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=900)